# How to secure ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file?

Tags: sshd

I have a machine with public key authentication enabled. I have some authorized keys at `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

I'm worried about the case I ever mistakenly run a malicious script/program with my user (with no root access). The script would be allowed to silently modify `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to allow an attacker to permanently obtain remote access to that user and further attack the system.

1. Is the default location for authorized keys (`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`) a security issue?
2. Is there a different approach to saving per-user authorized keys in a more secure way (i.e. requiring root access to allow new hosts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option in sshd config file: `AuthorizedKeysFile`

And using Tokens you could set it like this:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/sshd.keyfiles/%u.key
```

And the next step is to add this folder to your Puppet/Ansible/etc system and keep track on changes on all files in that folder.

Answer (score 4):

If you have root access on this machine, then you could try making your ssh files and directory immutable by using the [`chattr` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr), e.g.:

```bsh
sudo chattr +i ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chattr +i ~/.ssh
```

This will prevent your authorized keys file from being modified, renamed, deleted or overwritten. Since only root can unset the immutability flag, this would prevent any script you run as a regular user from inserting a key to your `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: Thank you! I would now wonder why is not a mechanism like this the default?

Comment: @AndresR Things being as they are, I don't think that this would be a very good default behavior. Every time you want to add a key to your authorized keys file, you would have to submit a request to your system administrator. And the sysadmin would have to unset the flag, add the key, and then reset the flag.

Comment: @AndresR It is a matter of convenience over security. The standpoint is "if there is malware running on your system, it already is too late". There is a myriad of possibilities for malware to open access to your system (e.g. place a reverse shell in the user's auto-start) – it does not make sense to protect against this particular attack (this would feel like a Microsoft thing to do – "we now protect against $foo" sounds good in marketing). Developers and admins should rather feel inclined never to have malware executed in the first place.

Comment: That is certainly the case of large multi-user systems. If I'm running a small server, where I work all the day, chances are at some point I'll run some code I didn't fully read, and risk the system. As I'm also the sysadmin, I'd be able to add a key.

Comment: @AndresR Though you can make a case for configuring my system as paranoid, I do not want a paranoid default.

Answer (score 0):

How is ssh secured against spoofing the home folder with 'mount --bind'? I did a test and and mounted the home folder with another folder on a different harddisk. After using the command ssh-copy-id, the key of the client was correctly imported into /home/.ssh/authorized_keys and after changing the access rights of the home folder with 'sudo chmod 755 ~' it worked like a charm and it was not longer necessary to enter a password.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/393862)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).